# edittext getSelection one touch behind

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have the following code:

```
    output.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG,"start and end " + output.getSelectionStart() + ", " + output.getSelectionEnd());
            start = Math.min(output.getSelectionStart(), output.getSelectionEnd());
            end = Math.max(output.getSelectionStart(), output.getSelectionEnd());
            output.setSelection(start, end);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Where output is an Edittext. The problem is, the onTouchListener is one cursor move behind. So if touch the Edittext at position 0, then at position 5, the log cat when touching position 5, says I'm at position 0. Also, the cursor always appears in the correct position...Any one else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that care, I solved(unsatisfactorily) the issue. It appears to be an unresolved bug in the Android OS. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=2188).